# adding css3 transforms to current css3 transform value

Tags: javascript, css, css-transforms

I have this element that after executing a certain javascript function, will make its css transform value to :

```
-webkit-transform : translateX(25px) translateY(25px) scale(1);
```

how do i get that value through javascript in the form of

`"translateX(25px) translateY(25px) scale(1)"` ?

What I really want to achieve is that I want to add a "`rotate(360deg)`" on mouseenter. I'm thinking i'll be able to achieve this if I get hold to its current transform value.

the :hover pseudo-class wouldn't do the trick because it will be overwritten by the current value of `-webkit-transform`

EDIT:

I forgot to mention that this is actually for a plugin i'm doing. The translate values are being set through html data-attributes and being extracted through jQuery's `.data()`.

Comment: Don't know about jQuery; will `$(element).css("-webkit-transform")` or `$(element).css("webkitTransform")` help?

Comment: that will return a matrix which isn't really what I want .

Comment: Though not exactly the same as "defined", `$(element).css()` seems to return the "computed" style, which should has the same effect as the original transform: http://jsfiddle.net/s5NTU/

Answer (score 0):

If the values are fixed an not computed by the script, I think that a better choice is to keep of css form javascript, so instead of hardcoding the animation value in your script you could simply create a couple of css rules, e.g.

```
.transformed {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(25px) translateY(25px) scale(1);
}
.transformed:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(25px) translateY(25px) scale(1) rotate(360deg);
}
```

After the first script execution, just add the `.transformed` class to your element.
Then you could leave the pseudoclass `:hover` work for you, without the need to use javascript for this task.

Otherwise if you need to mantain the `360deg` rotation also on `mouseleave`, just change the last rule into

```
.transformed.mouseenter {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(25px) translateY(25px) scale(1) rotate(360deg);
}
```

and on mouseenter event just add the `.mouseenter` class.

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not keep it off from javascript because the transform values are set through html data-attributes. I forgot to mention that i'm creating a plugin and translateX, translateY, scale are set by the user.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the context of your problem is, but it sounds like you need to use a css3 transition library such as [jQuery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) since you are using Javascript heavily. Examples:

```
$(".box").on("mouseenter", function () {

    $(".box").transition({x: '+=25', y: '+=25', scale: 1.5, rotate: 360 }, 500);

});

$(".box").on("mouseleave", function () {

    $(".box").transition({x: '-=25', y: '-=25', scale: 1, rotate: 0 }, 500);

});


var scaleFactor = 0.25;

$(".boxGrow").on("click", function () {

    $(".boxGrow").transition({scale: '+=' + scaleFactor }, 500);

});
```

### [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5sq4R/)